# How Does Autofac Handle Non-Disposable Components

Tags: c#, memory-management, autofac, idisposable

I have read that Autofac does a good job of [disposing `IDisposable` resources](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/index.html), but I'm having trouble finding any info on what it does with components that do not have any unmanaged resources, and therefore do not need to implement `IDisposable`.  I would assume these all get garbage collected, but is there any documentation on this scenario?

#### EDIT

Asking more specifically, are all Autofac-resolved components required to implement `IDisposable`?  The [docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html#) state that

> To take advantage of automatic deterministic disposal, your component must implement IDisposable.

Am I correct in understanding this refers to any kind of Autofac-resolved component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's petty good documentation from autofac on managing the disposal of the objects.

See: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html

Comment: You got this in right as I was editing :P So would that apply to all components?  I'm used to `IDisposable` only being needed if there are unmanaged resources.  Ask it another way, if I don't implement `IDisposable`, won't Autofac just not track it for disposal and the GC removes it like normal?

Comment: It depends on the lifetime scope of the registered component as well. Autoface will not auto release object that doesn't implement 'IDisposable'. You have to add additional handling for these. There's indeed specifications for handling of non 'IDisposable' object. See https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html#specified-disposal