# Is there a way to combine dependency injection with IDisposable?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

A colleague and I were just talking about unit testing when I realised that I write code differently in certain circumstances...

If I'm using Entity Frameworks on its own, I'll tend to use the `IDisposable` interface via a `using` block:

```
using (Context ctx = new Context()) { whatever(); }
```

But when I'm writing code that will be unit tested, I move the instantiation of the context into a constructor, so that I can pass in mocks to be used instead. I understand that this is a type of dependency injection, specifically "constructor injection".

Taking only a cursory look, I see this latter pattern recommended in a couple of articles:

- [Mocking Entity Framework when Unit Testing ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/mocking-entity-framework-when-unit-testing-aspnet-web-api-2)
- [Entity Framework Testing with a Mocking Framework (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_5)

The problem with this (as my colleague and I reflected) is that the dispose method is never called. I suppose these objects get finalised as they move out of scope, but it seems less than ideal.

So, my question: **is there a way to combine dependency injection with use of IDisposable?**

I can imagine three possible categories of answer:

1. "Yes, there is a way and here's how..."
2. "No, there isn't a way. This is something you'll have to live with."
3. "Tom, you have completely misunderstood something."

Whichever it is, we'd be really grateful!

Comment: 3. The container will dispose it, when you configure it to. This means you won't have to use `using () { }` anymore in your code.

Comment: Like CC says, the container will call `Dispose` if your object implements `IDisposable` at the right time depending on how you registered it.

Comment: What DI framework are you using? Or are you using constructor chaining and passing in a new `DbContext` instance from the default constructor (ie. you are not using a DI framework).

Comment: @Igor The latter. We're only using DI to inject mock DB contexts, so we're not using a full-blown DI container.

Comment: @CodeCaster We're not using a DI container, we're just passing an instance of a mock context to an overload of the default, parameterless constructor.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30287923/264697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The latter. We're only using DI to inject mock DB contexts, so we're not using a full-blown DI container.

You are correct, the `DbContext` instance will never have `Dispose` called on it (*assuming you are not manually calling dispose in one of your methods*). I recommend you select a good DI framework (my personal fav. is [AutoFac](https://autofac.org/)). The framework will handle disposing anything that implements `IDisposable`, is registered with the framework, and is injected/supplied by the framework.